# can client side events be managed from server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to make a simple .js file with some scripts like "window.open()". After the link opens it should click on a particular button on that link and download some files. Is it possible to do so ?

Comment: It is possible, You just have to send a proper request to a particular end-point from your server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
function printMousePos(event) {
  document.body.textContent =
    "clientX: " + event.clientX +
    " - clientY: " + event.clientY;
}

document.addEventListener("click", printMousePos);
```

when the button is clicked then another event will call for download.